# mysql update json field getting quoted

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the follonwing json structure stored into mysql

```
{
    "somefield": "0",
    "date": "2020-12-01",
    "caption": null,
    "field": [
        {
            "id_type1": "5192"
        },
        {
            "id_type2": "3285"
        },
        {
            "id_type2": "3638"
        },
        {
            "id_type2": "3750"
        },
        {
            "id_type2": "3760"
        },
        {
            "id_type1": "3161"
        },
        {
            "id_type1": "1044"
        }
    ],
    "question": "",
    "people": [],
    "title": ""
}
```

Whem I submit a form I want retrieve not empty values by their name and then update json field

Supose I have submitted 2 field, `date` and `field`
field

```
[{"id_type1":5192},{"id_type2":3285},{"id_type2":3638},{"id_type2":3750},{"id_type2":3760},{"id_type1":3161},{"id_type1":1044},{"id_type1":8081}]
```

date

```
'2021-04-02'
```

I wanne update json field with these values

```
UPDATE table
SET
json_champ = JSON_SET(json_champ, '$."field"', '[{"id_type1":5192},{"id_type2":3285},{"id_type2":3638},{"id_type2":3750},{"id_type2":3760},{"id_type1":3161},{"id_type1":1044},{"id_type1":8081}]', '$."date"', '2020-12-01')
WHERE id = '52907';
```

Everything goes right for date but field is escaped

```
"field": "[{\"id_type1\":5192},{\"id_type2\":3285},{\"id_type2\":3638},{\"id_type2\":3750},{\"id_type2\":3760},{\"id_type1\":3161},{\"id_type1\":1044},{\"id_type1\":8081}]"
```

Expected

```
"field": [{"id_type1":5192},{"id_type2":3285},{"id_type2":3638},{"id_type2":3750},{"id_type2":3760},{"id_type1":3161},{"id_type1":1044},{"id_type1":8081}]
```

If I paste expected output directly into PMA it works as expected

pasted

```
{
    "somefield": "0",
    "date": "2020-12-01",
    "caption": null,
    "field": [{"id_type1":5192},{"id_type2":3285},{"id_type2":3638},{"id_type2":3750},{"id_type2":3760},{"id_type1":3161},{"id_type1":1044},{"id_type1":8081}],
    "question": "",
    "people": [],
    "title": ""
}
```

Generated sql query

```php
<?php
$sqlUpdate = " UPDATE table 
SET 
json_champ = JSON_SET(json_champ, '$."field"', '".json_encode($fieldValues, , JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)."', '$."date"', '2020-12-01')
WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Comment: *I have the following json string* Your data string is JSON array. You cannot use JSON_SET() over it specifying the path specific for JSON object.

Comment: so what sould I do ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only difference is adding field to the beggining of json and then inserting the string into the table?

```
$json_string = '[{"id_type1":5192},{"id_type2":3285},{"id_type2":3638},{"id_type2":3750},{"id_type2":3760},{"id_type1":3161},{"id_type1":1044}]';
   
$ammended_string = json_encode(['field' => json_decode($json_string)]);

$sqlUpdate = " UPDATE table 
SET 
json_champ = '".$ammended_string ."'
WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

correct me if I'm wrong but think you might be overcomplicating this a little.

Comment: In fact I have more than one field into my json data query is build over submitted values in post if posted value exists into json, then take it and update json in mysql

Comment: well that wasn't in your question.